# Typo3 , extbase mapped entity return no results

Tags: typo3, extbase

First of all, i create a Extension with the "Extension Builder". I would like to extend the "tt_address" Extension.

**What steps i do?**

1. I create a Entity `Adress` and map this to existing table `tt_address`. In my Entity `Address` i create setter and getter for retrieving Addressinformations like 'city, zip and street'.
2. After this step i create a Repository `AddressRepository` which extends `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository`.
3. The extensionbuilder create a typoscript File `ext_typoscript_setup.txt` with this content:

   config.tx_extbase{
       persistence{
           classes{

   ```
           Mab\Oaaddress\Domain\Model\Address {
               mapping {
                   tableName = tt_address
                   recordType = Tx_Oaaddress_Address
               }
           }

       }
   }}
   ```
4. I set the `storagePid` in my `constants.txt`

In the last step i would like to retrieve all Addresses from Database and show this in a list view.

```
class AddressController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController {

    /**
     * Events repository
     *
     * @var \Mab\Oaaddress\Domain\Repository\AddressRepository
     * @inject
     */
    protected $addressRepository;

    /**
     * action list
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function listAction() {
        // Exists adress repository?
        //var_dump($this->addressRepository);
        $addresses = $this->addressRepository->findAll();
        //var_dump(count($addresses));
        $this->view->assign('addresses', $addresses);
    }
```

The table `tt_address` contains more than ten results. But the controller show  `$addresses` count always `0`. I clear every Cache (empty Typo3Temp folder, empty Cache through Install Tool, emptyh Backend Cache) but nothing have a effect. Why my Controller return nothing? Can someone give me a tip?

**Update**

After i analyse the query log, i find that this query is executed:

```
SELECT  tt_address.* FROM tt_address  WHERE 1=1 AND (tt_address.tx_extbase_type='Tx_Oaaddress_Address') AND tt_address.pid IN (148) AND tt_address.deleted=0 AND tt_address.hidden=0
```

How can i remove this part

tt_address.tx_extbase_type='Tx_Oaaddress_Address' from the where part of the query?

Comment: You can take a look at mysql's `general.log`. In your Terminal, find out where the logfile is (e.g. /var/log/mysql5/general.log) and then do
`tail -n 3000 /var/log/mysql5/general.log | grep tt_address`
This could help you to find the sql query that was called and you may see what is going wrong.

Comment: @jay-dinse Thank you a lot for your hint, i find the executed query and updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
config.tx_extbase {
    persistence {
        classes {
            FriendsOfTYPO3\TtAddress\Domain\Model\Address {
                mapping {
                    tableName = tt_address
                    recordType = Tx_TtAddress_Listview
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And add "Tx_TtAddress_Listview" to your tx_extbase_type like:
// Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_address.php

```
$tempColumnstx_yourext_tt_address[$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_address']['ctrl']['type']] = [
    'exclude' => true,
    'label' => 'yourLabe for Type',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'select',
        'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
        'items' => [
            ['Person','Tx_TtAddress_Listview'],
            ['MyLabel','Tx_YourExt_type']
        ],
        'default' => 'Tx_TtAddress_Listview',
        'size' => 1,
        'maxitems' => 1,
    ]
];
```

This adds a or to the SQL statement like:

```
... WHERE ((`tt_address`.`t
   x_extbase_type` = Tx_YourExt_type) OR (`tt_address`.`tx_extbase_type` = Tx_TtAddress_Listview) ...
```

Comment: This does not answer the question as it changes the `AND` in SQL to `OR`, it does not remove the part as OP tries.